# OpenGL lighting question

Tags: c++, opengl

I have got all my OpenGL lighting working properly, with the normals, materials, ect...

My problem is the way in which OpenGL renders the faces when the light is behind the face. If the light is behind a face, it should render a black face, but instead it renders what the backface of the face would look like. How do I stop this strange behaviour. I find it hard to describe what is happening, but hopefully you know how to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Okay, say I have a flat square polygon to reperesnt a wall. Whichever side I have the light on, both get lit up even though only one side should be lit and the other should be black (or very dark because of other/ambient light). See the problem? It is like paper because the light is just going through and showing up on the wrong side of the face.

Comment: Do your vertices have normals?

Comment: Yes, there is nothing wrong with the normals.

Comment: You haven't set the `GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT` to bright?

Comment: Okay, it was the light's ambience...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are seeing occurs because both sides of the polygon use the same normals in their lighting calculations.

The solution to this is to set:

```
float modelTwoside[] = {GL_TRUE};
glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_TWO_SIDE, modelTwoside);
```

This causes OpenGL to reverse the normals before rendering the back side.
OpenGL will also use the back material.

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Then I don't know what the problem is, perhaps you could make a minimal test case that demonstrates the problem and show us.